# What service does automatically mount my second HDD?

Tags: mount

On my ubuntu, some drives are automatically mounted on `media/user/`, however I don't have anything on `/etc/fstab`.

I would like to understand how it is mounted and when?

Comment: Your drives are mounted by udev: `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules`

Comment: @A.B. just out of curiosity, could you explain which part of this file is responsible for mounting in `/media/$USER/`